# Symfony 3 - automatically serialize DateTime object

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

In my project I have some entity with `createdAt` column.

```
//...
class Acme
{
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $createdAt;
}
```

I have enabled `FOSRestBundle` with Symfony serializer:

```
fos_rest:
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '/', fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
```

I make select from datebase in `AcmeRepository`:

```
public function methodName() 
{
   $qb =  $this->createQueryBuilder('d');
   $s = $qb->select('d.createdAt']);

   return $s->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

And in result, in my controller:

```
$res = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Acme')->methodName();
return $res;
```

It's returns json, but instead of `[{"created_at": "2016-04-04 12:13:13"}]`  i'm getting this:

```
[{"created_at":{"timezone":{"name":"UTC","location":{"country_code":"??","latitude":0,"longitude":0,"comments":""}},"offset":0,"timestamp":1459769277}]
```

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the format of the Type defined for the FOS REST module with the proper annotation Type (check [here](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type) the doc). As example:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type as JMS;

class Acme
{
    /**
     * @var DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     * @JMS\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>")
     */
    protected $createdAt;
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Maybe you known solution with the Symfony Serializer?

Comment: an example of deserializing datetime object with the symfony serializer component can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#using-callbacks-to-serialize-properties-with-object-instances) in the doc

Comment: is it possible to configure `DateTime<'Y-m-d'>` globally?

Comment: Hi @112Legion IF you're using the JMSSerializerBundle, you could try the datetime settings under the key handers [here](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/configuration#extension-reference)