# Date not display in responce (symfony3, doctrine)

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, controller

My controller:

```
class LoggingController extends Controller
{
    public function getLogAction()
    {
        $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(ChangeLog::class)->findAll();
        if ($result === NULL) {
            return new View("Log not found", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return new View($result,Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

My doctrine orm.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\ChangeLog:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\ChangeLogRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        date:
            type: datetime
#...and other
```

When I try to display my records from table, I receive this in date (date is empty):
[image]

But in my table in db everything are normal:
[image]
What is wrong? All another data displays normally...
I use FosRestBundle for displaying data in JSON format.

Comment: What happens if you return a json response?

return new JsonResponse($result);

Comment: @Louis return this: `[
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
]`

Comment: @Louis is still correct, you need a Serializer, otherwise it doesn't know how to respond the DateTime object (assuming you're expecting a string format).

Comment: check e.g. this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428688/symfony-3-automatically-serialize-datetime-object

Comment: @LBA   thanks, I will try